# Rasa Chatbot - Issue in executing actions.py file with mysql database connectivity

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

Encountered an exception while running action 'action_email_data'.The bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MEHUL\Anaconda3\envs\RasaMehul3\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\actions\action.py", line 721, in run
response = await self.action_endpoint.request(
File "C:\Users\MEHUL\Anaconda3\envs\RasaMehul3\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\endpoints.py", line 173, in request
raise ClientResponseError(
rasa.utils.endpoints.ClientResponseError: 500, Internal Server Error, body='b'{"description":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"message":"The server encountered an internal error and cannot complete your request."}''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MEHUL\Anaconda3\envs\RasaMehul3\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\processor.py", line 868, in _run_action
events = await action.run(
File "C:\Users\MEHUL\Anaconda3\envs\RasaMehul3\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\actions\action.py", line 745, in run
raise RasaException("Failed to execute custom action.") from e
rasa.shared.exceptions.RasaException: Failed to execute custom action.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error code suggests that there was a server error. Did you start the action server before making any requests to the bot? If you are running your bot locally, you can start the action server with:

```
rasa run actions
```

See the doc reference at [Running a Rasa SDK Action Server](https://rasa.com/docs/action-server/running-action-server/).